# Python Twitter Api: AttributeError: module 'twitter' has no attribute 'trends'

Tags: python, twitter

```
import twitter
import json



OAUTH_TOKEN='aaa'
OAUTH_SECRET='bbb'
CONSUMER_KEY='ccc'
CONSUMER_SECRET='ddd'

          auth=twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api=twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)


print(twitter_api)




WORLD_WOE_ID=1
world_trends=twitter.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
print(world_trends)
```

I always get the error:
`AttributeError: module 'twitter' has no attribute 'trends'`

Comment: You changed the OAUTH_TOKEN/SECRET and CONSUMER_KEY/SECRET before you posted this, right?

Comment: I've removed your keys - please revoke them from the Twitter console.

Comment: I didn't change them. Maybe the stackoverflow.com automatically changed it for me? I was also surprised about this, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.trends` on an instance of `Twitter` instead of the module. This should work for you:

```
import twitter
import json 

OAUTH_TOKEN='aaa'
OAUTH_SECRET='bbb'
CONSUMER_KEY='ccc'
CONSUMER_SECRET='ddd'
auth=twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api=twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)    

print(twitter_api)   

WORLD_WOE_ID=1
world_trends=twitter_api.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
print(world_trends)
```

Comment: Thank you Terence! After installing several different twitter.api packages from https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries , under the 'Python'. I eventually got the code running out of the results.  I don't know which one took effect but guess I was lucky anyway.